# how to create human resource management in system?

Tags: android

can you please tell me how to call json web service using how to call json webservice using asynctask android .I call like that and got the response.But I need to do like that before calling i need to show "please wait " do some async task in background.and remove that pop up when response come.

```
    public static String getMethod(String url) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else {
                // Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }


 WebServiceRequestManager wb=new WebServiceRequestManager();
       String ss= wb.getMethod("htoard?crsCode=add");
       System.out.println("String"+ss);
```

Comment: You maybe want to try something like https://github.com/koush/ion

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would to use AndroidAsyncHttp(LoopJ) for the following reasons.
1) Code structure will be small and elegant.
2) Easy to use.
3) Performance ,it is really fast

Answer (score 0):

DO this way

This is your **WebServiceRequestManager.java**

```
public class WebServiceRequestManager {

    public String getMethod(String url) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else {
                // Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

}
```

**How to call it from Activity from asynctask?**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                showProgressDialog("Please Wait...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                WebServiceRequestManager manager = new WebServiceRequestManager();
                return manager.getMethod("http://50.57.145.165:8080/FirstGroupRailApps/jservices/rest/a/destinationdashboard?crsCode=add");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                System.out.println("Respose : " + result);
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void showProgressDialog(final String msg) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (progress == null || !progress.isShowing()) {
                    progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void hideProgressDialog() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();
                } catch (Throwable e) {

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```